# Java: How to shadow a field used in a parent method from a child?

Tags: java

I have an abstract parent class in Java (which I never use directly) and multiple children of that class. Parent class contains a method that is exactly the same for each children, apart from a single String field, which is constant for each children as is not meant to be changed or different between subclass instances. Without reimplementing said method in each subclass and not polluting parent constructor signature, how can I let children reuse parent's method with their own constant?

Example code:

```
class Animal {
    // The field in question. SHOULD be enforced to be unique and not have itself needlessly
    // duplicated in each and every class instance. Animals won't lose or gain legs, this
    // property is predetermined at compile time, is hardcoded, and will not be changed
    // throughout normal program execution. COULD have its signature changed, static is
    // for example and is not enforced.
    protected static int legs = 4;

    // Internal state of the parent class which is used by its children through
    // helper/getter/setter methods.
    private Zoo zoo;

    // Constructor requires specific data. SHOULD NOT have its signature or content changed.
    Animal(Zoo zoo) {
        this.zoo = zoo;
    }

    // The method in question. It already requires extra data to process it, and actual code
    // is much larger; MUST NOT be duplicated in subclasses; SHOULD NOT have its signature changed.
    // "Person's skill is determined by the maximum amount of legs the animal can have
    // for them to be able to ride it."
    boolean isRideableBy(Person person) {
        system.out.println(Integer.toString(this.legs));
        return (person.animalRidingSkill >= this.legs);
    }
}

class Centipede extends Animal {
    // My intention is to use field shadowing to change how inherited method behave.
    protected static int legs = 100;
  
    // Child constructor SHOULD be as easy as super(zoo), without requiring any extra
    // work on subclass's end.
    Centipede(Zoo zoo) {
        super(zoo);
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to simply have my `legs` constant shadowed by the child so that it would be used instead of parent's in parent method, but Java seems to have a different opinion, which brings me here.

Any field signatures I tried on `legs` failed. I also tried implementing a getter for `legs`, but it doesn't get the modified value from the children:

```
class Animal {
  ...
  int getLegs() {
    return this.legs;
  }
  ...
}
```

My intention is to make a common method that would allow me to set a property (`legs`) that outside code MUST NOT be able to change, because that would otherwise compromise app security. At the same time, I need to be able to change the amount of `legs` as easily and effortlessly as possible without having to worry about anything else. I want the parent method to be a warehouse of template methods, implementations of which is depend only on said `legs`.

To me it seems almost inevitable that I will have to shove `legs` into a parent constructor, but I want to ask why must I do that? Why can't a parent method perform its functions with shadowed child fields? And if there is no way to achieve that, why parent constructor is the only way, if my **constants** will be different only between different children? To me it just seems like I would pollute a constructor while breaking some kind of convention in Java that I don't know about. Shouldn't there be a more elegant solution that is more in line with the semantics of my problem?

Comment: Why does the field need to be static?

Comment: @stdunbar, I care about conserving memory, and storing this variable in each and every instance feels wrong when *all* of them in a same class will have the same value. So I would love to not let it be too wasteful here if possible.

Comment: If it's static, it should be final.

Comment: The answer below is correct but you are prematurely optimizing code if you're worried about 4 bytes.  Unless you're going to run this in a Javacard environment with 256kb of memory you'll spend all your time *thinking* that you've optimized the code and never actually delivering anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Fields are determined at compile time. If you want polymorphism in subclasses in Java, you override methods.